# Illustrator layers to keynote presentation

Tags: adobe-illustrator, keynote

(I'm using AI CC and Keynote 6)

Often I would have a complex diagram that I would like to show part by part animated in my presentation. Nothing fancy that would require after effects, just appearing in a sequence. I use Illustrator to make those diagrams and I can easily separate them such that the sequence I want to show are **arranged in layers**.

But my final presentation is in Apple keynote. What is the best way to import them?

In the past, I have exported each build as `png`. But this is quite labor intensive, and aligning them in keynote over multiple pages could be a pain. I could try to write an illustrator script, but that seems to be more work than I am willing to put in...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest keeping them as PNGs but setting the artboard to the same ratio as your keynote (leaving lots of white space around the object for titles and any other text), duplicate the artboard and make any changes you wish. This may take a little time at first to work out your rough layout in Keynote, but once you have that, keeping everything in the same place will be easy.

[image]

File > Export all of the art boards as PNGs.

[image]

Place your PNGs onto your master slides. If you have created them as the same ratio as the Keynote, you should have no issue getting them to line up.

[image]

Comment: This is a great answer. If your `Artboard` in Illustrator has the same pixel dimensions as your Keynote slides they will center themselves when you insert them to Keynote.